# Xpages Mobile CSS: iOS7

Tags: css, mobile, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have an Xpages app and I want to surface some pages from that app into my iPhone App. I want the Xpages pages to look like iOS7 so the users have the same experience in the app and don't know they are not in a native app.

IBM has not updated their mobile CSS yet.

But there is some CSS that goes a long way to fixing this:

http://redpilldevelopment.com/xpages-mobile-controls-ios7-theme/

I was able to make script library in my app and then I was able to get the CSS into a page, all using the instructions on the site.

What I don't get is how to make my app use the css theme? When I view the page on my iPhone some of the page is rendered like ios7, but much is not. Do I have to match up each individual element on the page to the class in the custom css?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your page I guess.  Not every control has a "mobile renderer".  DataView does for instance but viewPanel does not.  So that could be why you're seeing it fine for some things but not others.

I believe in 9.01 with the latest extension pack it's easier to override the mobile them.  It had been pretty difficult before.  I think that's why your linked article mentions that the iOS7 theme can't be in the Head tag.

You might need to override styles for anything that doesn't look like iOS7.

Comment: That is what I thought. I am able to do that OK in the data page. Can't figure out what to override in the RoundedList to get the lines to look like they do on iOS7. I am using Dev Tools on browsers to try to figure out which CSS element is the border for the element, but haven't got it yet. Will keep trying.